# how to show the version number when we hover on the .msi file using WIX

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3, velo

When the mouse hovers over the .msi file, a tooltip should popup that shows the version of the application:

[image: Version Number on Hover for MSI]

I want to display version number within this description box
so what can I add in my code so that I got this version number in this box when I hover over the .msi file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***PUT-GUID-HERE***: For all samples, replace "PUT-GUID-HERE" with a GUID. You can generate one here: https://www.guidgenerator.com/

---

There could be an easier way to do this, but it seems to be possible to "re-purpose" the **`Comments attribute`** in the Package element for this - here is a snippet, the relevant part is the "Comments" attribute:

```
<Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" Comments="Version: 1.0.993" />
```

***Screen shot***:

[image: MSI Hover]

***Full Sample***:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="*" Name="HoverVersionNumber" Language="1033" Version="1.0.993" 
                    Manufacturer="Tester" UpgradeCode="PUT-GUID-HERE">
    
        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes"
                 InstallScope="perMachine" Comments="Version: 1.0.993" />

        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
        <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />

        <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="HoverVersionNumber" Level="1" />

  <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="HoverVersionNumber">
          
          <Component Feature="ProductFeature">
            <File Source="C:\Windows\Notepad.exe" />
          </Component>
        
      </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>

  </Product>

</Wix>
```

Now using a preprocessor define entry to allow version number to be set once and applied wherever needed - the **`$(var.MyVersion)`** markup will expand to the version number in the define statement (allowing a single location to update the version number provided the markup is up to date everywhere in the source):

***Snippets***:

```
  <?define MyVersion  = "1.0.993"?>

  <..>

  <Product Id="*" Name="HoverVersionNumber" Language="1033" Version="$(var.MyVersion)" 
           Manufacturer="Tester" UpgradeCode="PUT-GUID-HERE">
    
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" 
             InstallScope="perMachine" Comments="Version: $(var.MyVersion)" />
```

***Full Sample***:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">

  <?define MyVersion  = "1.0.993"?>
  
    <Product Id="*" Name="HoverVersionNumber" Language="1033" Version="$(var.MyVersion)" 
             Manufacturer="Tester" UpgradeCode="PUT-GUID-HERE">
    
        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" 
                 InstallScope="perMachine" Comments="Version: $(var.MyVersion)" />

        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
        <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />

        <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="HoverVersionNumber" Level="1" />

  <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="HoverVersionNumber">
          
          <Component Feature="ProductFeature">
            <File Source="C:\Windows\Notepad.exe" />
          </Component>
        
      </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>

  </Product>

</Wix>
```